# Select Columns based on Values in Column

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I am using `tidyverse` and I am aware of the `filter` method which allows to filter all rows that have a value that matches a specific condition such as the following. It filters for all rows that have a value between 0 and 3 in at least on column.

```
filter_all(any_vars(. > 0 & .<3))
```

How can I do the same on column basis? If my `tibble` looks like the following I want to write a `select` that returns all columns that have in at least one row a value greater than 4 (should return columns B,C)

```
    | A | B | C |
    -------------
    | 1 | 1 | 2 |
    | 2 | 5 | 1 |
    | 3 | 6 | 9 |
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `select` with `any`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      select_if(~ any(. > 4))
```

-output

```
#  B C
#1 1 2
#2 5 1
#3 6 9
```

---

Or use `where` as in the new version

```
df1 %>%
    select(where(~ any(. > 4)))
#  B C
#1 1 2
#2 5 1
#3 6 9
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) any(x > 4), df1)
```

Or with `sapply`

```
df1[sapply(df1, function(x) any(x > 4))]
```

or with `colSums`

```
df1[colSums(df1 >4) > 0]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = c(1, 5, 6), C = c(2, 1, 9))
```